# How to use Roles in ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with LocalDB?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I would like to manage users and roles with the default ASP.NET MVC 5 membership in a **LocalDB** database file in the app_data folder.  This is automatically created if it does not exist.

I wrote a role editor, but when I attempt to apply roles to the Web API as follows:

```
[Authorize(Roles= "SystemAdmin")]
```

, the role manager attempts to call a stored procedure inside the database.

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.
```

This stored procedure would normally be created in a full SQL Server membership database created by the **aspnet_regsql** utility, however the **aspnet_regsql** utility only operates on a full SQL Server database and not on a LocalDB database.

Is there any way to tell the Role Provider not to make this stored procedure call without having to write a Role Provider from scratch?  I have my database connection defined as follows -

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DefaultConnection.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an alternate solution - a custom RoleProvider that works with **LocalDB** .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using MyApp.Models;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The purpose of this role provider is to support membership + roles in a MSSQL LocalDB.
    /// It works around the limitation of the standard SqlRoleProvider
    /// which requires stored procedures in a SQL Server database.
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public override string ApplicationName { get; set; }


        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var user = usersContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || u.Email.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));


                if (user == null) return new string[] { };

                var roles = from ur in user.Roles
                            from r in usersContext.Roles
                            where ur.RoleId == r.Id
                            select r.Name;
                if (roles != null)
                    return roles.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { };
            }

        }


        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            foreach(var userName in usernames)
            {
                var roles = GetRolesForUser(userName);
                foreach(var roleName in roleNames)
                {
                    if (!roles.Contains<string>(roleName))
                    {
                        using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
                        {
                            var user = usersContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                            if (user != null)
                            {
                                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                                if (role != null)
                                {
                                    var userRole = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole();
                                    userRole.RoleId = role.Id;
                                    userRole.UserId = user.Id;
                                    user.Roles.Add(userRole);
                                }
                            }
                            usersContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                return usersContext.Roles.Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
            }
        }


        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            return this.GetRolesForUser(username).Contains(roleName);
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            role.Name = roleName;

            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                usersContext.Roles.Add(role);
                usersContext.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            var usersInRole = GetUsersInRole(roleName);
            if (throwOnPopulatedRole)
            {
                if (usersInRole.Length > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Role " + roleName + " is not empty");
                }
            }

            var roleNameArray = new string[1];
            roleNameArray[0] = roleName;
            RemoveUsersFromRoles(usersInRole, roleNameArray);

            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                if (role != null)
                {
                    usersContext.Roles.Remove(role);
                    usersContext.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                return (role != null);
            }
        }


        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {

            foreach (var userName in usernames)
            {
                var roles = GetRolesForUser(userName);
                foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
                {
                    if (!roles.Contains<string>(roleName))
                    {
                        using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
                        {
                            var user = usersContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                            if (user != null)
                            {
                                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                                if (role != null)
                                {
                                    var userRole = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole();
                                    userRole.RoleId = role.Id;
                                    userRole.UserId = user.Id;
                                    user.Roles.Remove(userRole);
                                }
                            }
                            usersContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                var users = from ur in role.Users
                            from u in usersContext.Users
                            where ur.RoleId == u.Id
                            select u.UserName;
                if (users != null)
                    return users.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { };
            }
        }


        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            var regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(usernameToMatch);

            using (var usersContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var role = usersContext.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(roleName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                var users = from ur in role.Users
                            from u in usersContext.Users
                            where ur.RoleId == u.Id
                            && regEx.IsMatch(u.UserName)
                            select u.UserName;
                if (users != null)
                    return users.ToArray();
                else
                    return new string[] { };
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Surely thousands of people have to write this same thing because there's no canned solution for this?